# I want to adapt a VFD

Tags: voltage, mains

If I feed single phase electricity into a 3 phase input VFD, I know it needs to be derated on the output by about 50%, but how does it cope with the difference in voltage, as rectified 230v rms gives 1.414 * 230 = 325v dc, but rectified 415v gives 1.35 * 415 = 560 vdc. How does it produce the correct PWM wave form voltages?

Comment: The shape of the waveform doesn't change with DC bus voltage, but the amplitude of the output will scale linearly.

Answer (score 1):

If your single phase is 230V then your 3ph isn't going to be 415V - it'll be 398V. OK back to the question - on the basis that you haven't specified which variable frequency drive I'd strongly advise against it because the smoothing capacitor inside the VFD will not be able to cope. This is what 3ph looks like rectified (no smoothing cap): -

[image]

Notice that the ripple voltage is very small (red) - now for comparison, here's what single phase looks like rectified: -

[image]

Notice that the single phase that is full wave rectified will inevitably drop down to 0V every half cycle and will need an appropriately sized capacitor to keep the ripple voltage low between peaks of the AC. This isn't needed on a 3ph VFD and, even if it had one, it would be no good for smoothing a single phase because it would be far too low in value to hold up the supply between half cycles.

Comment: This makes sense, but couldn't you provide such an output capacitor or am I missing some VFD context?

Comment: @sherrellbc - where would you fit it - is there access - I don't know because the OP hasn't given any detail of the VFD. It would also be on the live side of things and seriously dangerous for a beginner to work with.

Comment: SOME VFD's allow access to the DC Bus and most VFD's seem to have a DC Bus smoothed by capacitors. But I would consult the manual before adding extra capacitence just in case its opperation depends on knowing the DC Bus capacitence.